# Unable to update values in a column after minimum requirement was changed

Tags: column

I'm using SharePoint 2010.  I had a number column set to require a unique entry with a minimum value of 5000.  After about 40 entries were made to the list the minimum value requirement was changed to 3000.    Editing pre-existing entries to change the value to a number under 5000 errors out with a message "Only values greater than or equal to 5000 are allowed."  Is it possible to retro-fit this change to the existing list entries so I can modify the values - without using coding?

Comment: To clarify, I can edit the data in the datasheet view and the change is accepted, but the error remains, i.e., the field is still outlined in red.  And if you try to edit the list item in Standard View, you are unable to save the change because of the  error in the item.

Answer (score 0):

You could just bulk edit the columns in the page using the quick edit feature in the toolbar for the list.

Answer (score 0):

The SharePoint Management Shell commands can be used to update the minimum value. Change the site url, list and column names.

```
$web = Get-SPWeb("site_url")
$list = $web.Lists["list_name"]
$field= $list.Fields["column_name"]
$field.MinimumValue = 3000
$field.update()
```

Hope that helps.